# WMS service output tiles with more then 255 Colors

Tags: geoserver, wms

The default Geoserver WMS implementation allows an output of png tiles with up to 256 Colors defined by a SLD style definition.

In conjunction with a GLSL approach to color tiles client side, I want to render tiles with more then 255 colors. Instead using the full RGB range (256 * 256 * 256) is what would be needed.

Is Geoserver or an alternative Tile generating server solution able to render 24 bit png images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I download the PNG from my GeoServer, it has RGB color profile:

```
curl -o layer.png http://localhost:8080/geoserver/test/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=test%3Amunicipalities&bbox=498306.7970000002%2C5235854.617999479%2C855882.5630006271%2C5602020.779999593&width=749&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A25832&styles=&format=image%2Fpng

gdalinfo layer.png
[...]
Band 1 Block=749x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=749x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=749x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Only when I explicitly request `format=image/png8`, I get a 1 Byte paletted PNG:

```
gdalinfo layer8.png
[...]
Band 1 Block=749x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 255 entries)
    0: 0,0,0,255
[...]
  254: 255,255,255,255
```

You can also request `format=image/tiff` if that helps you more.
See [WMS output formats documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/services/wms/outputformats.html) for the full list.

Lastly, would it help you to request [vector tiles](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/index.html) and do the rendering completely on the client side?

Comment: Thank you for thinking along. I finally found out that defining `extended="true"` allow a ramp colormap to interpolate much more detailed. 

This answer also helps explaining the issue.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/183118/182867